# Why would LayoutObjectNames return an empty string in FileMaker 14?

Tags: filemaker

I'm seeing some very strange behavior with FileMaker 14. I'm using `LayoutObjectNames` for some required functionality. On the development system it's working fine. It returns the list of named objects on the layout.

I close the file, zip it up and send it to the client, and that required functionality isn't working. He sends the file back and I open it and get a data viewer up. The function returns nothing. I go into layout mode and confirm that there are named objects on the layout.

The first time this happened and I tried recovering the file. In the recovered file it worked, so I assumed some corruption had happened on his end. I told him to trash the file I had given him and work with a new version I supplied. The problem came up again.

This morning he sent me the oldest version that the problem manifested in. I confirmed the problem, tried recovering it again, but this time it didn't fix the problem.

I'm at a loss. It works in the version I send him, doesn't on his system. We're both using FileMaker 14, although I'm using Advanced. My next step will be to work from a served file instead of a local one, but I have never seen this type of behavior in FileMaker. Has anyone seen anything similar? Any ideas on a fix? I'm almost ready to just scrap the file and build it again from scratch since we're not too far into the project.

Thanks, Chuck

Comment: What is the exact calculation you are using, and what is the exact file name?

Comment: `LayoutObjectNames ( Get ( FileName ); Get ( LayoutName ) )`. FileName in this case (I've confirmed the problem in multiple versions of the file) is `Jada1.03.fmp12`. `Get ( FileName )` correctly returns `Jada1.03`. Interesting idea, perhaps the client is renaming it with the dot and that's the problem? I'll experiment in that direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue with the `Get (FileName)` function when the file name contains dots (other that the one before the extension). I will amend my answer later with more details and a possible solution (I have to look it up).

---

Here's a quote from 2008:

> This is a known issue. It affects not only the ValueListItems()
>   function, but any function that requires the file name. The solution
>   is to include the file extension explicitly in the file name. This
>   works even if you use Get (FileName) to return the file name
>   dynamically:
>
> `ValueListItems ( Get ( FileName ) & ".fp7" ; "MyValueList" )`
>
> Of course, this is not required if you take care not to use period
>   when naming your files.

http://fmforums.com/forums/topic/60368-fm-bug-with-valuelistitems-function/?do=findComment&comment=285448

Apparently the issue is still with us - I wonder if the solution is still the same (I cannot test this at the moment).